# Javascript - Get only two decimals on selected element

Tags: javascript, html

I would like some help here.
I need to get only two decimals on the VAT field.

Thanks in advance for any help

```js
$('select').change(function() {
var selected_value = $('#sel option:selected').val();
  
var no_VAT = document.getElementById('no_VAT');
no_VAT.innerText = selected_value;
  
var VAT = document.getElementById('VAT');
VAT.innerText = selected_value * 0.23;
  
var with_VAT = document.getElementById('with_VAT');
with_VAT.innerText = selected_value * 1.23 ;  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector" id="sel">
<option value="10">2</option>
<option value="12">3</option>
<option value="18">6</option>
</select>

<p id="no_VAT"></p>
<p id="VAT"></p>
<p id="with_VAT"></p>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your number result to 2 places after the decimal by using [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var VAT = document.getElementById('VAT');
VAT.innerText = (selected_value * 0.23).toFixed(2);
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since `fixedTo()` returns a String, if you want to make sure the result is still a number (if you want to work with it later, for example) simply parse it as a float.

```
VAT.innerText = parseFloat((selected_value * 0.23).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: `parseInt` is not needed ?

Comment: @RayonDabre not in this case because `* 0.23` automatically casts the result to a number before `toFixed()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Change to **selected_value * 0.23** to **(selected_value * 0.23).toFixed(2)**

```js
$('select').change(function() {
var selected_value = $('#sel option:selected').val();
  
var no_VAT = document.getElementById('no_VAT');
no_VAT.innerText = selected_value;
  
var VAT = document.getElementById('VAT');
VAT.innerText = (selected_value * 0.23).toFixed(2);
  
var with_VAT = document.getElementById('with_VAT');
with_VAT.innerText = selected_value * 1.23 ;  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector" id="sel">
<option value="10">2</option>
<option value="12">3</option>
<option value="18">6</option>
</select>

<p id="no_VAT"></p>
<p id="VAT"></p>
<p id="with_VAT"></p>
```